# NSWindowWillCloseNotification is received when exiting full screen

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, appkit, nswindowcontroller

In my 3D application, I handle `NSWindowWillCloseNotification` to perform cleanup (stop display link, release resources, etc.). The app can run in two modes, OpenGL and Metal. There is a `ViewBase` class that implements common functionality and among other things handles the notification.

Everything works fine in OpenGL mode, however in Metal mode, the `NSWindowWillCloseNotification` is received when exiting fullscreen window causing the app to stop showing anything. The only meaningful difference between Metal and OpenGL is that Metal view uses backing layer, but I do not know why this may matter.
I am totally confused why this could be happening and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, I was setting notification handler in `awakeFromNib`, where `[self window]` was nil. So notification handler was set of null window. I fixed the problem by referencing the main application window instead: `auto* mainWindow = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow];`